# How to find the first positive integer number that is not in the list

Tags: c#, algorithm, list

Suppose I have a number list, each one inside is unique and ordered:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>
  {0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 15};
```

Then I want to add a new number, the number must be unique, its value should be the minimum one which can be inserted in the "hole" of the list.

In this case, the first new number should be **2**, then **5**, then **6**,... .

Another example, if the list is:

```
{0, 1}
```

Then the new number should be **2**

Do you have some good idea to implement this algorithm, thanks.

Comment: Do _you_? What is your question? What have you tried? You need a variable and a loop...

Comment: I changed the title as L0laapk3 suggested, now this title should be more accurate. Thanks @L0laapk3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the first positive integer number that is not in the list. (since you're using "the" first number, I assume you don't need an array of numbers with all holes.)

The way you do this is (assuming the array is sorted like in your examples) is by simply starting with zero and adding one until the array doesn't contain the number:

```
int[] arrayWithNumbers = new int[] {0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 15};

int i = 0;
while (arrayWithNumbers.Contains(i)) //check if number already exists in array
{
    i++; //increment by 1
}

Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you understand correctly. But for your code, I think should be :    while (arrayWithNumbers.Contains(i))  without not-operator.

Comment: right, sorry. I quickly threw this together without testing it :) I changed it now

Comment: thanks, your answer is lean and nice.

Comment: Don't forget to accept helpful answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new[] { 0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 15 };
var holes = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Max()+2).Except(list).ToList();
```

Comment: "Here, I did your homework". At least explain what this code does. This also won't fulfill OP's second requirement, returning a hole beyond the end of the list (2 when the list is {0, 1}).

Comment: I checked the code, it can return the holes list not only for the first requirement, but also the second requirement( in this case, the list contains 1 element which is 2), thanks. Only one problem, for the first requirement, the hole list contains 16, I think it should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Just *sort* the list out and then check:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> {
  0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 15
};

// if the list is ordered, you don't need this
list.Sort();

// if list is dense 
int result = list[list.Count - 1] + 1;

// check for "holes", providing that list values are unique (list[i - 1] != list[i])
for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; ++i)
  if (list[i - 1] + 1 != list[i]) {
    result = list[i - 1] + 1;

    break;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is correct